# Сбой сканирования документов на файловый сервер (SMB)

Tags: администрирование

Помогите решить не могу.
сбой сканирования документов на файловый сервер (SMB)
есть Xerox 5325 настроил сканирование по протоколу SMB.
на некоторые пк работает. 
На 2х пк ошибку выдаёт **027-529 data read failure from smb server**

Comment: http://www.fixya.com/support/t9952773-completed_error_027_529_data не оно?

Comment: Да оно, походу из-за того что пользователь подключён через 8 портовый хаб, а хаб к cisco